# Error with SQL query in C#: Using SELECT JOIN WHERE OR

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

SQL is still relatively new to me but I have generated this from research I have done.

This is my sql command:

```
"SELECT Array_ID 
 FROM Array_Location JOIN 
      Obj_Type.Type_ID ON Array_Location.Obj_Type 
 WHERE (Obj_Type.Object = 'CIRCLE') 
    OR (Obj_Type.Object = 'POLYGON');"
```

This is my error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'WHERE'

This is a syntax problem but i'm not sure on the solution

The two tables I have are:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Type] (
[Type_ID] INT  NOT NULL,
[Object]  TEXT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_OBJ_TYPE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Type_ID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Array_Location] (
[Array_ID]   INT NOT NULL,
[Obj_Type]   INT NOT NULL,
[Element_ID] INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Array_Location_fk0] FOREIGN KEY ([Obj_Type]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Obj_Type] ([Type_ID]) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Typo sorry. I do have that included in my code. So still same error

Comment: Update your question to reflect the exact code you have used

Comment: I have done. Solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want, You also need conversion to cast `TEXT` to `varchar` or `nvarchar`

```
SELECT Array_ID 
FROM Array_Location JOIN 
     Obj_Type ON Obj_Type.Type_ID = Array_Location.Obj_Type 
WHERE (Convert(nvarchar(max),Obj_Type.Object) = N'CIRCLE') OR (Convert(nvarchar(max),Obj_Type.Object) = N'POLYGON');
```

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:**

You have syntax error in JOIN:

```
Array_Location JOIN Obj_Type.Type_ID ON Array_Location.Obj_Type
```

**Solution:**

```
SELECT Array_ID 
FROM Array_Location JOIN 
     Obj_Type ON Obj_Type.Type_ID = Array_Location.Obj_Type 
WHERE (CONVERT(nvarchar(50),Obj_Type.Object) = N'CIRCLE') 
   OR (CONVERT(nvarchar(50),Obj_Type.Object) = N'POLYGON');
```

Comment: Good luck with comparing Text and varchar

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh: Ah! you are right! I was no idea about the datatype before OP edited his question. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Not only you have a syntax error in your join, but also I think you are executing two scripts for creating tables together in SQL Server? If you run them together, you will usually get this error:

> Foreign key `Array_Location_fk0` references invalid table
>   `dbo.Obj_Type`

Before you correct your join query, you must correct create tables script in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Obj_Type] (
[Type_ID] INT  NOT NULL,
[Object]  TEXT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_OBJ_TYPE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Type_ID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Array_Location] (
[Array_ID]   INT NOT NULL,
[Obj_Type]   INT NOT NULL,
[Element_ID] INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Array_Location_fk0] FOREIGN KEY ([Obj_Type]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Obj_Type] ([Type_ID]) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: I had just copied it from Visual Studios. But I did have the created properly. Good spot though thanks. I have amended it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT Array_ID FROM Array_Location JOIN Obj_Type.Type_ID ON Array_Location.Obj_Type WHERE (Obj_Type.Object = 'CIRCLE') OR (Obj_Type.Object = 'POLYGON');
```

you miss parenthesis (')') in end of statement in where

Answer (score 0):

You may miss to address the array_ID table name and also wrong syntax in `JOIN`. Try this.

```
 SELECT Array_Location.Array_ID 
 FROM Array_Location 
     INNER JOIN Obj_Type 
     ON Array_Location.Type_ID = Obj_Type.Type_ID 
 WHERE (Obj_Type.Object = 'CIRCLE') OR (Obj_Type.Object = 'POLYGON')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ending close bracket for **Obj_Type.Object = 'POLYGON'**.SQL Server WHERE clause always expects the condition to be evaluated as boolean value (true/false). 
Please change the query to the following:

> `SELECT Array_ID FROM Array_Location JOIN Obj_Type.Type_ID ON Array_Location.Obj_Type WHERE (Obj_Type.Object = 'CIRCLE') OR (Obj_Type.Object = 'POLYGON');`